# Elavon Converge Pay - What is ssl_test_mode?

Tags: credit-card

Anyone know what the field `ssl_test_mode` do in Elavon Converge Pay XML request?

If you take the [Credit Card Transaction > Sale](https://developer.elavon.com/#/api/eb6e9106-0172-4305-bc5a-b3ebe832f823.rcosoomi/documents/?converge-integration-guide/book/transaction_types/credit_card/sale.html) they give the following example:

```
<txn>
    <ssl_merchant_id>my_merchant_id</ssl_merchant_id>
    <ssl_user_id>my_user</ssl_user_id>
    <ssl_pin>my_pin</ssl_pin>
    <ssl_test_mode>false</ssl_test_mode>
    <ssl_transaction_type>ccsale</ssl_transaction_type>
    <ssl_card_number>00*********0000</ssl_card_number>
    <ssl_exp_date>1215</ssl_exp_date>
    <ssl_amount>1.00</ssl_amount>
</txn>
```

But, I can't find any place that document what the field `ssl_test_mode` do or what values it expects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found some information in a PDF document at page 342:

https://www.nationaltransaction.com/SalesReps/Converge/VM%20developerGuide.pdf

- **Field name** : ssl_test_mode
- **Length**: 5
- **Default**: FALSE
- **Description**: Optional when set to true. Transactions
  will not be forwarded to the credit card
  processor, but instead will always return
  an APPROVED result.

But, it's not from Converge official documentation.